# RePrompt user for camera access after deny

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

I am currently working on a project for a streaming application that prompts the users for features like:  Permission for Microphone Access, Screen share access, microphone access, etc.  Part of the parameters for the assignment is to re-prompt a user  for permission if they accidentally pressed denied.  From my understanding that permissions are session based and only after a deny the user can either refresh the page or manually make the change in settings.

Is there a way in javascript to enforce a reprompt or is my initial session correct.  From my understanding it is one of three "Always Allow"  "Always Deny" "Session based".

We are working with Javascript, Node, and WebRTC.

Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can try refreshing the page using `window.location.reload()`. Even in this case **it will only work if user has not pressed always deny**.

You cannot re-ask for permission without refreshing the page because the browser blocks the request automatically to protect the privacy of the user. But, you can write a script to not allow the user to join a meeting or a classroom if the user has not allowed Microphone / Camera access. This is done in most cases.

Request to accept the answer if it helps...